# Как закрыть сообщение при клике

Tags: javascript

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('.remove-button');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.parentNode.classList.remove('el');
  })
}
```

```css
  body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
  }

  .pane {
    background: #edf5e1;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
  }

  .remove-button {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: darkred;
    right: 10px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  .el{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="messages-container">
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл или ишак — одомашненный подвид дикого осла, сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека. Все одомашненные ослы относятся к африканским ослам.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Корова, а также пара слов о диком быке, о волах и о тёлках. </h3>
      <p>Коро́ва — самка домашнего быка, одомашненного подвида дикого быка, парнокопытного жвачного животного семейства полорогих. Самцы вида называются быками, молодняк — телятами, кастрированные самцы — волами. Молодых (до первой стельности) самок называют
        тёлками.
      </p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-button');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.parentNode.classList.add('el');
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
  }

  .pane {
    background: #edf5e1;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
  }

  .remove-button {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: darkred;
    right: 10px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  .el{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="messages-container">
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл или ишак — одомашненный подвид дикого осла, сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека. Все одомашненные ослы относятся к африканским ослам.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Корова, а также пара слов о диком быке, о волах и о тёлках. </h3>
      <p>Коро́ва — самка домашнего быка, одомашненного подвида дикого быка, парнокопытного жвачного животного семейства полорогих. Самцы вида называются быками, молодняк — телятами, кастрированные самцы — волами. Молодых (до первой стельности) самок называют
        тёлками.
      </p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте я правильно понял у меня ошибка в том что я класс удалял, а его надо было добавить ?

Answer (score 2):

1. var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('.remove-button') - точка лишняя ведь поиск идет не по css селектору а по classname 
   var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-button') - так верно
2. this.parentNode.classList.remove('el'); - судя по всему надо не удалить стиль а наоборот навесить его 
   this.parentNode.classList.add('el'); - так верно

Comment: понятно спасибо

Comment: Там кстати, можно лишний раз не создавать переменную и сразу записать `buttons[i].addEventListener`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME хочу, хочу, хочу,  увидеть код пожалуйста :))

Comment: @Leks https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/s3zgoc5f/ - да я про строчку `var button = buttons[i]` - на каждом круге внутри for() заново создается переменная и используется только один раз - в следующей строке. Тогда и весь смысл пропадает) Переменные можно создавать, если элемент будет использоваться по несколько раз. Или если оно будет содержать длинноватый кусок кода, в который легче вникать, глядя на название переменной)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME посмотрел код, понятно, спасибо